# Converting DataSet to String or Int

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have a function that gets a SQL command and returns a dataset.  Now I'm trying to run this string command:

```
@"SELECT ProductPrice 
FROM Products 
Where ProductPrice IN 
(
  SELECT ProductPrice 
  FROM Products 
  WHERE  ProductName =N'" 

+ listBox1.Text 
+ "')").Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString()
```

`ProductPrice` is an `INT`
`ProductName` is a `NVARCHAR`

I'm getting this result in the textbox:

' System.Data.DataRow '

BTW : This is a SCHOOL PROJECT! I know this may be vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: Say, if the query is going to return a max of 1 row with 1 field (ProductPrice), I suggest you use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `DataAdapter.Fill` etc.

Comment: What did you expect in the textbox? You are doing `ToString()` on a `DataRow` object. Certainly you'd have to iterate over the actual fields in the Row to find their values. Notice that I'm trying to give you a direction to follow instead of the actual answer.

Comment: Well i used the **ToString()** trick with another query and it works just fine so i thoght it will be the same ..

Comment: @ShmulikCohen `ToString()` can give a sensible result when used on a value type, imagine an `int` with value `5` and you do `ToString()` it will be able to produce a string `"5"`. However, when you use `ToString()` on a reference type (an object with potentially more than 1 value), what it is it supposed to return? It will by default tell you the type of the object. In your case `DataRow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a homework question, I'm going to stick to the [guidelines for homework questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and try to be helpful without giving you a full answer.

> - Try to provide explanation that will lead the asker in the correct direction. Genuine understanding is the real goal for students, but
>     trying to provide that is seldom unappreciated for any question.
> - It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment. You
>     can use pseudo-code first, and, in the spirit of creating a
>     programming resource, you may come back after a suitable amount of
>     time and edit your response to include more complete code. This way,
>     the student still has to write their own code, but a full solution can
>     become available after the assignment has ended.

---

First, you're missing some code in your sample, but based on the results, I'm assuming that you have something like this in your code:

```
TextboxResults.Text = MyTable.Rows[0].ToString();
```

The reason you're getting System.Data.DataRow is that you're only referencing the row (the first row in the table that's filled by your data adapter), which is a collection of objects.

Hint: In your select statement, the price is in the **first element inside** (0 based index) the Row that you're already referencing.

Shorter version: You're referencing the first row of the table.  You need to reference the contents of the first cell in the first row in the table.

Since being a good developer often means knowing how to use search, I'd Google the following phrase and apply what I've just told you and you should have your answer:

*how to access a particular datarow's cell in a table*

**Second hint:**

If I were going to ***write*** to the contents of the first cell in the first row it would look like this:

```
myTable.Rows[0][0] = 1.99;
```

instead of

```
myTable.Rows[0] = 1.99;
```

Comment: ok i will google it , i need it for the rest of my project . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Shmulik,

I guess you try to print using `dataRow.ToString()`.
C# does not know how to print an object of type DataRow since the object may contain different columns.
If you want to print ProductPrice, try `dataRow[0].ToString()` instead.

Comment: Gena ,
i dont have the option to do , dataRow[0].ToString() .